# Unity - Register Generic Type With Interface Parameters

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

I am attempting to implement CQRS by following this [article](http://web-matters.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/cqrs-with-aspnet-mvc-entity-framework.html), I have got everything working but I cannot work out how to register all of the IQueryHandler types in Unity.

I have the following classes:

```
// query
public class GetTitleByIdQuery : IQuery
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

//result
public class GetTitleByIdResult : IQueryResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

// handler
public class GetTitleById : IQueryHandler<GetTitleByIdQuery, GetTitleByIdResult>
{
    public async Task<GetTitleByIdResult> Retrieve(GetTitleByIdQuery query)
    {
        var context = new MyContext();
        return await context.Titles.Where(i => i.Id == query.id).Select(i => new GetTitleByIdResult {Id = i.Id, Description = i.Description}).SingleAsync();
    }
}
```

If I explicitly register the type it get resolved correctly e.g.

```
container.RegisterType<IQueryHandler<GetTitleByIdQuery, GetTitleByIdResult>, GetTitleById>();
```

Is resolved by:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IQueryHandler<TParameter, TResult>));
```

However this would mean that I would have to manually register each type, ideally I would like to do something like:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
     AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(type => typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).IsAssignableFrom(type)),
            WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces, WithName.TypeName, WithLifetime.Transient);
```

When I try this none of the types are registered, I think it is because they are not assignable, for example this is not valid syntax:

```
IQueryHandler<IQuery, IQueryResult> test = new GetTitleById();
```

The author of the original article seems to be able to do this using Ninject, is the same possible in Unity?

Comment: In my experience, it is much better to have a generic `IQuery<TResult>` interface, instead of using a non-generic `IQuery`. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) for a detailed description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an extension method `RegisterAllTypesForOpenGeneric`, something like:

```
 container.RegisterAllTypesForOpenGeneric(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GetTitleById )));
```

with:

```
public static class UnityExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterAllTypesForOpenGeneric(this IUnityContainer container, Type openGenericType, Assembly targetAssembly)
    {
        if (!openGenericType.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            throw new ArgumentException("typeToRegister must be an open generic type", "typeToRegister");

        foreach (Type type in targetAssembly.GetExportedTypes())
        {
            if (openGenericType.IsInterface)
                RegisterInterfaceTypes(container, openGenericType, type, type);
            else
                RegisterBaseTypes(container, openGenericType, type, type);
        }
    }

    private static void RegisterInterfaceTypes(IUnityContainer container, Type openGenericType, Type targetType, Type typeToRegister)
    {
        foreach (Type interfaceType in targetType.GetInterfaces())
            if (interfaceType.IsGenericType && !interfaceType.ContainsGenericParameters && openGenericType.IsAssignableFrom(interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
                container.RegisterType(interfaceType, typeToRegister);
    }

    private static void RegisterBaseTypes(IUnityContainer container, Type openGenericType, Type targetType, Type typeToRegister)
    {
        if (targetType.BaseType != null && targetType.BaseType != typeof(object))
            if (targetType.BaseType.IsGenericType && openGenericType.IsAssignableFrom(targetType.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
                container.RegisterType(targetType.BaseType, typeToRegister);
            else
                RegisterBaseTypes(container, openGenericType, targetType.BaseType, typeToRegister);
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.danderson00.com/2010/09/automatically-register-implementors-of.html